# I've written identical code for DataSet and DataTable. Can this be DRY'd?

Tags: c#, generics, datatable, dataset, ado.net

I find that I've written the same code twice. There's this, with DataSet

```cs
public static DataSet foo(SqlCommand)
{
    var Adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
    // The important line:
    DataSet Output = new DataSet();
    Adaptor.Fill(Output);
    return(Output)
}
```

and this with DataTable

```cs
public static DataTable foo(SqlCommand)
{
    var Adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
    // The important line:
    DataTable Output = new DataTable();
    Adaptor.Fill(Output);
    return(Output)
}
```

Is there any way to remove this repetition? My attempts with generics have failed, since the compiler can't know that what I'm passing in is always safe to `Fill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this code can't be DRY'd because there's no `Fill` overload that takes in an interface or a class that is a common base to both `DataSet` and `DataTable`.

There's also no way to use generic constraints in the form of or -
You can't have a generic method where T is one of several unrelated types (by related I mean, of course, polymorphic interchangeable) so a attempting to write your method like `static T foo<T>(SqlCommand cmd) where T : DataSet or T : DataTable` will not compile.

However, given the fact that these are only four lines of code that's being duplicated, I think it's not really a problem.